# Laravel no objects anymore

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, forge

I've got a problem with `ssl` in my `Laravel 5.3` application. For some reason when I activate it on `Laravel forge` with `LetsEncrypt` it's not being send as an `object` anymore. This is how I receive it `without ssl`:

(It's a `console.log(data)` within `vue.js 1.0`)

[image]

This is with `ssl`:

[image]
So with `ssl` I cannot say `data.token` anymore because that will be undefined (it's a string).

In my `controller` I'm returning like this:

```
 return response()->json(compact('token'))
                         ->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

The Content-Type is `Content-Type: "application/json"` with or without `ssl` so that cannot be the problem...

So basically my entire application i useless with `ssl`!

I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what's going on. Searched everywhere but I cannot find a solution.

Comment: Anyone? Really need to fix this.

Comment: Can't you check and see if it's typeof === string and then do a json decode if it is, otherwise access the object directly?

Comment: You should intercept the response and run `JSON.parse(res)`